# Expose API in Python for a PHP web app?

Tags: php, python, api, web-applications

I want to create a stock picking game just to challenge my friend to see who does best with say, a million dollars. I am planning on using a Python module to fetch the stock data from Yahoo finance API. I then want my friend to login and buy/sell stock with the virtual dollars he has from the web app (PHP).

So, how do I interface the Python module to that of the web app? I am hoping I made some sense!

Comment: Why not pick one language for the whole project?  Why would you make a program to fetch data from an API, just to expose an API so another program could read it?  If you must use two languages in this way, why not just use a shared database?

Comment: Are you doing this to learn or so you can play a game?  If it's just to play a game search google for "stock picking game" and use one of the websites already created for this purpose.

Comment: I will be fetching real-time data from Yahoo (no shared db), that is what my Python script does. Not sure if I can accomplish the same with PHP - then that will eliminate Python.

Comment: @ Steven : Both learning as well as playing. I looked at fantasy stock picker sites but I want it to be just among small group of friends with zero clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Tonnes of ways:

- HTTP (look into Tornado Web or similar)
- Sockets
- A database (such as MySQL)
- Hell, even a textfile

That's assuming of course that you actually want the Python running continuously. A cron job might work fine too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: I still don't understand where a database fits in this scenario(apart from login info, buy/sell info). I am using a Python script to fetch real-time data from Yahoo which will eventually be stored in MySQL db.

Comment: It really depends what you want to do. If the Python is just doing a load of processing, fetching the finance data, etc, then you have that running in the background doing the work. Then you have a PHP site which is the interface to the processed data in the database.

Comment: Hmmm, for instance say the user will enter a ticker and then the ticker value and other info are fetched. So, yes the Python script should be fed the ticker and the PHP app should get the values returned by the Python script. The interaction between them both is what I wanted to know. But yeah, I am working on an all PHP solution.